# dotNET : remote connection on SAME machine -- is it possible?

Tags: c#, windows-services, remote-access, tcp

I am having a C# based winforms or ASP.NET application deployed on my laptop which has to remotely connect to a windows service. The protocol mentioned in config file is TCP-IP as follows:

```
<wellknown url="tcp://LaptopMachineNAme:8085/MyService" type="MyController, MyOwn.AppTier" />
```

What would happen if the 'windows service' is also installed on my laptop?... Will the winforms or ASP.NET application be able to establish the "remote connection on the SAME machine"...???

Comment: I believe only local firewall which block all incomming connections could be a problem, what have you tried and with which issues have faced? BTW, this si offtopic for SO, ask question on the SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem connecting to the service which is installed on the same computer. I would use [named-pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx) for this task, there is no problem having 2 (or more) bindings to the same service.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't even pass the FW IMO, when trying to connect to *yourself*...

I've done some projects that are using WinForms/ASP.NET combined with Windows Services on the same host - works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

I've tested pretty many solutions having client and server working on the same machine. Should work. You can use localhost as machine name.